# VPN клиент OpenVPN не видит большие пакеты от сервера

Tags: сеть, vpn, openvpn

Подключаюсь к офисному серверу OpenVPN на CentOS 6.9. Логинюсь на него и все отлично, до тех пор пока не выведешь большой кусок информации типа `man tcpdump` или даже просто листинг директории с множеством фалов `ls -l`, после этого терминал просто подвисает и ничего нового не появляется на экране.

Запустил `tcpdump` на клиенте и сервере (в фоне естественно и писать в файл, а потом файл забрал) чтобы посмотреть что же происходит с пакетами.

Как мне кажется проблема в том что я - ноут - клиент не отправляю подтверждение серверу на большой пакет.

Вот лог c клиента:

```
08:27:05.015536 IP 10.21.34.46.49314 > 192.168.200.1.ssh: Flags [P.], seq 4942:4982, ack 5486, win 4096, options [nop,nop,TS val 439936696 ecr 969946599], length 40 

08:27:05.021312 IP 192.168.200.1.ssh > 10.21.34.46.49314: Flags [P.], seq 5486:5526, ack 4982, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 969955308 ecr 439936696], length 40 

08:27:05.021383 IP 10.21.34.46.49314 > 192.168.200.1.ssh: Flags [.], ack 5526, win 4094, options [nop,nop,TS val 439936701 ecr 969955308], length 0 

08:27:05.059860 IP 192.168.200.1.ssh > 10.21.34.46.49314: Flags [P.], seq 5526:5582, ack 4982, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 969955348 ecr 439936701], length 56 

08:27:05.059938 IP 10.21.34.46.49314 > 192.168.200.1.ssh: Flags [.], ack 5582, win 4094, options [nop,nop,TS val 439936739 ecr 969955348], length 0 

08:27:05.102096 IP 192.168.200.1.ssh > 10.21.34.46.49314: Flags [P.], seq 6910:7990, ack 4982, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 969955390 ecr 439936739], length 1080 

08:27:05.102191 IP 10.21.34.46.49314 > 192.168.200.1.ssh: Flags [.], ack 5582, win 4096, options [nop,nop,TS val 439936781 ecr 969955348,nop,nop,sack 1 {6910:7990}], length 0
```

Предпоследняя строка где пришел пакет длиной `1080` (байт?), по аналогии с предыдущими должен после последовать бы `ack 7990` от меня - но его нет.

То же самое время, лог с сервера:

```
08:27:04.995863 IP 10.21.34.46.49314 > 192.168.200.1.ssh: Flags [P.], seq 1201:1241, ack 1608, win 4096, options [nop,nop,TS val 439936696 ecr 969946599], length 40
08:27:04.997398 IP 192.168.200.1.ssh > 10.21.34.46.49314: Flags [P.], seq 1608:1648, ack 1241, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 969955308 ecr 439936696], length 40
08:27:05.001432 IP 10.21.34.46.49314 > 192.168.200.1.ssh: Flags [.], ack 1648, win 4094, options [nop,nop,TS val 439936701 ecr 969955308], length 0
08:27:05.037639 IP 192.168.200.1.ssh > 10.21.34.46.49314: Flags [P.], seq 1648:1704, ack 1241, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 969955348 ecr 439936701], length 56
08:27:05.040060 IP 10.21.34.46.49314 > 192.168.200.1.ssh: Flags [.], ack 1704, win 4094, options [nop,nop,TS val 439936739 ecr 969955348], length 0
08:27:05.079294 IP 192.168.200.1.ssh > 10.21.34.46.49314: Flags [.], seq 1704:3032, ack 1241, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 969955390 ecr 439936739], length 1328
08:27:05.079301 IP 192.168.200.1.ssh > 10.21.34.46.49314: Flags [P.], seq 3032:4112, ack 1241, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 969955390 ecr 439936739], length 1080
08:27:05.082312 IP 10.21.34.46.49314 > 192.168.200.1.ssh: Flags [.], ack 1704, win 4096, options [nop,nop,TS val 439936781 ecr 969955348,nop,nop,sack 1 {3032:4112}], length 0
08:27:05.282278 IP 192.168.200.1.ssh > 10.21.34.46.49314: Flags [.], seq 1704:3032, ack 1241, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 969955593 ecr 439936781], length 1328
08:27:05.688257 IP 192.168.200.1.ssh > 10.21.34.46.49314: Flags [.], seq 1704:3032, ack 1241, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 969955999 ecr 439936781], length 1328
08:27:06.500304 IP 192.168.200.1.ssh > 10.21.34.46.49314: Flags [.], seq 1704:3032, ack 1241, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 969956811 ecr 439936781], length 1328
08:27:08.124279 IP 192.168.200.1.ssh > 10.21.34.46.49314: Flags [.], seq 1704:3032, ack 1241, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 969958435 ecr 439936781], length 1328
08:27:11.372262 IP 192.168.200.1.ssh > 10.21.34.46.49314: Flags [.], seq 1704:3032, ack 1241, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 969961683 ecr 439936781], length 1328
08:27:17.868316 IP 192.168.200.1.ssh > 10.21.34.46.49314: Flags [.], seq 1704:3032, ack 1241, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 969968179 ecr 439936781], length 1328
```

Как видно перед пакетом длиной 1080, который дошёл сервер оказывается отправлял еще один побольше - 1328 и он не доходил. После того как были отправлены эти два больших пакет клиент послал ack  на пакет 1704, мол вижу всё вплоть до твоих больших пакетов, после чего сервер несколько раз ещё пытался слать пакеты начиная с 1704 безуспешно ожидая от клиента подтверждения.

В чём может быть дело?

Проблема пропадает иногда если использую другого провайдера, но сейчас с домашнего провайдера и с мобильного интернета, а так же ещё с одного провайдера - проблема сохраняется.

Конфиг OpenVPN:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote 1.2.3.4 1194
remote 5.6.7.8 1194
resolv-retry infinite
key-direction 1
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-256-CBC
verb 3
mssfix 1432
```

Спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 0):

Дело оказалось в большом "mssfix", заработало при значении 1420. Такое же значение в настройках роутера тплинк. Но разработчики мне так и не объяснили почему было выбрано именно 1420, ну типа все так делают и мы тоже. Хотя если посчитать, mtu можно делать и больше для pptp. А именно pptp у меня тип подключения.